# Making sure every Alphabet is in a string (Kotlin)

Tags: string, kotlin, intellij-idea, string-matching

So I have a question where I am checking if a string has every letter of the alphabet in it. I was able to check if there is alphabet in the string, but I'm not sure how to check if there is EVERY alphabet in said string. Here's the code

```
fun isPangram (pangram: Array<String>) : String {
    var panString : String
    var outcome = ""

    for (i in pangram.indices){
        panString = pangram[i]

        if (panString.matches(".^*[a-z].*".toRegex())){
            outcome = outcome.plus('1')
        }
        else {outcome = outcome.plus('0')}

    }
    return outcome

    }
```

Any ideas are welcomed Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be easier to check if all members of the alphabet range are in each string than to use Regex:

```
fun isPangram(pangram: Array<String>): String =
    pangram.joinToString("") { inputString ->
        when {
            ('a'..'z').all { it in inputString.lowercase() } -> "1"
            else -> "0"
        }
    }
```

Comment: This makes much more sense. I'm still a bit new with Kotlin and what I can do with it. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is how you can make with regular expression

Kotlin Syntax

```
fun isStrinfContainsAllAlphabeta( input: String) {
return input.lowercase()
  .replace("[^a-z]".toRegex(), "")
  .replace("(.)(?=.*\\1)".toRegex(), "")
  .length == 26;
}
```

In java:

```
public static boolean  isStrinfContainsAllAlphabeta(String input) {
  return input.toLowerCase()
 .replace("[^a-z]", "")
 .replace("(.)(?=.*\\1)", "")
 .length() == 26;
}
```

the function takes only one string. The first "replaceAll" removes all the non-alphabet characters, The second one removes the duplicated character, then you check how many characters remained.

Comment: Cool, but I am looking for a Kotlin solution for it. Not a Java one.

Comment: sorry I wrote regardless of the syntax since the transition is about just to find the corresponding Kotlin method. Anyway, I added also the Kotlin syntax

Answer (score 0):

Just to bounce off Tenfour04's solution, if you write two functions (one for the pangram check, one for processing the array) I feel like you can make it a little more readable, since they're really two separate tasks. (This is partly an excuse to show you some Kotlin tricks!)

```
val String.isPangram get() = ('a'..'z').all { this.contains(it, ignoreCase = true) }

fun checkPangrams(strings: Array<String>) =
    strings.joinToString("") { if (it.isPangram) "1" else "0" }
```

You could use an [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#extension-functions) instead of an [extension property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#extension-properties) (so `it.isPangram()`), or just a plain function with a parameter (`isPangram(it)`), but you can write stuff that almost reads like English, if you want!